# Oracle SQL - How do i select tables with 0 or more values from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Soo i need to make a consult that shows the id of the city, name, and how much clients that city have including cities that have 0 clients;

I was first trying to just get the cities that have clients but have no ideia on how to include cities that have no clients.

I have a table: CITIES that cointains ID_city, NAME, and REGION 
 and the table: CLIENTS that cointains ID_client, NAME and ID_city

query:

```
select l.name, l.ID_city, count(c.name) from clients c
JOIN cities l on l.ID_city = c.ID_city
GROUP BY l.name, l.ID_city;
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `left join`

```
select l.nomecidade, l.codcidade, count(c.nomecliente) from prova.clientes c
left  JOIN prova.cidades l on l.codcidade = c.codcidade
GROUP BY l.nomecidade, l.codcidade
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join but make sure which table you considering first.
The code below should solve the problem:

```
select C1.name, C1.ID_city, count(C2.name) from cities C1
LEFT JOIN clients C2 on C1.ID_city = C2.ID_city
GROUP BY C1.name, C1.ID_city;
```